# JavaScript - SetTimeout() - Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, recursion

Twice today I came across the following code snippet:

```
function draw() {
    setTimeout(draw, 100);
    // Drawing code goes here
}
draw();
```

This code must get out of sync if the drawing part takes longer than 100 milliseconds?

Comment: try and use `requestAnimationFrame` rather than doing a `setTimeout`

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Yes, of course, not only because drawing code fault or delay. It's just because settimeout could get out of time or late if navigator/OS are busy. Are you looking for a more precise way to achieve it?

Comment: shouldn't `draw` recall itself once it's done at the end of the function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: If he is looking for a function that is called once at 100ms that would be the best way... but he must separate computing movements and update of sprites, objects, ect from rendering them, so he could use another way to call computing function every 100ms to maintain linear movements and updates from scene actors, but jump render (drop frame, don't render it) if it is out of time. Because of this I asking him about what is he looking for exactly.

Comment: I know about requestAnimationFrame but I just was curious because apparently the old way used to be like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with you, it is not a best practice and it may definitely lead to cross-over calls. To "patch" it in a fast way, you can create an external lock (if not global), to mark of the previous execution has done it's job, and if not, just exit.

A better solution, in case of animations, is to use the native function [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), as pointed out by [Callum Linington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330137/callum-linington).

Comment: Totally right, I added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: I just wanted to verify my assumption, I know about the requestAnimationFrame - anyway, thanks for the reassurance!